# Features driven buildchain

Tags: c++, build-process

Quite often meet situation.

We have big project supporting few releases (lets assume hardwares) which differs a little on i.e. interfaces, filesystem, whatever.
Now, product management tell us - introduce NEW RELEASE, new hardware platform, but remain backward compatible.

1. **Use dynamic item selection** - by some clever HW variant detection I can declare on which release binary is being run and by if's run only necessary code. Obvious problem is that in production and released code all features are delivered to client and binary file is bigger (some releases have memory limitations).
2. **Static selection by file** - for build process we take only files under specific directory. That leads to lost of code duplication as REL1/REL2/RELx... will contain lots of common code with minor/major modification.
3. **Static selection by file parts** - most obvious approach - C++ preprocessor and IFDEFs. In long time will lead to code overflow with IFDEFs for any small/big problem. Current code contain minimal amount of IFDEF and we want to remain with this.
4. **There's other static solution** - use some kind of precofiguration phase in build process which will find and identify code/features specific for given release/HW variant. This is some variation of IFDEFs approach limiting preprocessor usage.

**Question** - which approach is better? How to solve this situation? Any other better approaches?

Comment: in one word: YES. in a bit more: pick one (or rather a mixture) which is the most appropriate for the task. the 2nd one is almost never a good idea.

Comment: We use solution 2 right now and third new HW variant is so different from HW 1 and only little from HW2 (with subfamilies) that ... we feel the pressure of duplicated code.
Where's flexibility? Rhetorical question ;)

Comment: How about good old autoconf?